# Configure return value mock with decorator only

Tags: python, mocking, python-mock, magicmock

Is there a way to capture the following logic in the `patch` decorator instead of having to pass the mock into the function:

```
@patch('boto3.client')
def test_playing_with_saml(self, boto3_client):
    boto3_client.return_value.assume_role_with_saml = lambda *args, **kwargs: ('foo', 'bar')
    self.assertEqual(playing_with_saml(), 'expected')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not really, not without speccing out the rest of `boto3_client`, which is *not* going to be clearer or more readable.

I'd not use a `lambda` here, I'd set the return value of the mock instead:

```
boto3_client.return_value.assume_role_with_saml.return_value = ('foo', 'bar')
```

Now you can make assertions about the `boto3_client.return_value.assume_role_with_saml` method (like asserting it has been called).

Comment: I didn't know you could chain it like that! Cheers.